# submitting x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm working on submitting a form that redirects the user to a new page.

this is a simplified version of the form:

```
<form method="post" id="form1"action="www.myweb.com/myform.asp">
    <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="value1">
    <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="value2">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In the past I've been able to submit  forms through url, like:

www.myweb.com/myform.asp?name1=value1&name2=value2

But this won't work now.

I'm struggling, and I think it is due to being x-www-form-urlencoded.  I'm unfamiliar with this, and could use some guidance.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using POST as a method of submitting your form. If getting something in the form www.myweb.com/myform.asp?name1=value1&name2=value2 you should use the GET method. Try changing your flag.

Comment: It's not that I'm having trouble submitting the form.  It's that I can't submit through URL.  Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

POST data should be submitted via `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>` element .

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GET to retrieve those values on myform.asp, you should make the form method="get" instead of "post".

GET will pass your data in the URL like that.

Check this out:

```
<form method="post" id="form1"action="www.myweb.com/myform.asp">
    <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="value1">
    <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="value2">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This will open "www.myweb.com/myform.asp" and pass name1 and name2 which can be recovered using $_POST['name1'] and $_POST['name2'] (in php at least, I don't know if it's the same in asp).

Now, if you take the same form but change form method to get:

```
<form method="get" id="form1"action="www.myweb.com/myform.asp">
    <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="value1">
    <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="value2">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This will open "www.myweb.com/myform.asp?name1=value1&name2=value2" and those values can be recovered using $_GET (in php, I don't know if it's different in asp).